# AND / OR conditions cakephp FIND for has many association

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I have a model Post that has many association with the model Comment.

Post has a primary key post_id which is Comment s foreign key.

Both of these have a visible column.

I have a working query on Post.visible options, and I need to add the AND to find all Posts that have one of Post.visible values.

For these posts I need all Comments that have a Comment.visible value = 1.

**My code:**

```
$conditions = array(
                    "OR" => array(
                        "Post.visible" => array(
                            1,
                            2,
                            3,
                            4
                        ),
                    ),
                    "AND" => array (
                        "Comment.visible" => 1
                    )
                );

$result = $this->Post->find('all', array(
                'order' => 'Post.created DESC',
                'conditions' => $conditions
        ));
```

The result without the AND is OK (but I get also the Comments with visible = 0).

When I put the condition "Comment.visible" => 1 in the has manyassociation, it works well (but I can not do this, because I need to get the Comment with visibility 0 elsewhere).

With the and it shows this Error:

**Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]:** Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Comment.visible' in 'where clause'

When I dump the SQL, the comments table is not even matched in the SELECT clause (nor in the LEFT JOIN).

Comment: you cannot query with conditions in hasMany directions directly. you need to make subqueries here. Only HasOne, BelongsTo can directly be queried with conditions inside a single query.

Comment: So basically I build the $this->Comment->find('first', conditions=>array('Comment.visible' => 1, 'Comment.post_id' => 'Post.post_id')); elsewhere and then I can use it inside the "main" condition?

How about performance?

Comment: @IgorLacik Have you tried to use the `contain` option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can limit another model's results using [CakePHP's Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) with something like this (this should work, but feel free to tweak per your needs):

```
//Post model
public $recursive = -1;

public $actsAs = array('Containable');

public function getPosts() {
    $posts = $this->find('all',
        array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Post.visible' => 1
            ),
            'contain' => array(
                'Comment' => array(
                    'conditions' => array('Comment.visible' => 1)
                )
            )
        )
    );
    return $posts;
}
```

Or, you can set up your association to only ever pull `comments` that are `visible` (even WITH this way, I still recommend using 'contain' like above - you just wouldn't need to specify the condition each time):

```
//Post model
public $hasMany = array(
    'Comment' => array(
        'conditions' => array('Comment.visible' => 1)
    )
);
```

Comment: It will not work because of recursive level -1, try change the recursive level to 2 then it will fine

Comment: @Cakephp.Saint - that is NOT correct.  It MUST be -1 for Containable to work.  Besides that, suggesting using recursive 2 is incredibly bad advice.

Comment: Dave: 

thx for this advice, really helped. 

I knew about the setting up of the association in the has many, but had to be able to see also comments with other values.

Didnt know about containable and am really thankfull for that.

Comment: Igor - glad to help! Containable is awesome - you'll love it.  Set recursive to -1 in your AppModel, and never look back.  :)  (seriously though - really do)

Comment: @Dave I accept ur point , but if we use recursive -1 it will take from only that table and not related tables know.. we need to put 1 or 0 incase of -1

Comment: @Cakephp.Saint - that's the point - use Containable instead of relying on recursive.