# Searching data from associated models in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, search, model-associations

I am using CakePHP 2.3.6. In my project, I have to search users using some values/data/parameter, which are in several tables, and the tables are associated.

The associations are :

in the model `User.php` :

```
public $hasMany=array('Education'=>array(
                        'className'=>'Education
                        'foreignKey'=>'user_id'
                  ),
                  'Experience'=>array(
                        'className'=>'Experience',
                        'foreignKey'=>'user_id'
                  ),
                  'Employment'=>array(
                        'className'=>'Employment',
                        'foreignKey'=>'user_id'
                  ),
                  'ProfessionalQualification'=>array(
                        'className'=>'ProfessionalQualification',
                        'foreignKey'=>'user_id'
                  )
)
```

in the model `Education.php` :

```
public $belongsTo=array('User'=>array(
                        'className'=>'User',
                        'foreignKey'=>'user_id'
                    )
)
```

in the model `Experience.php` :

```
public $belongsTo=array('User'=>array(
                        'className'=>'User',
                        'foreignKey'=>'user_id'
                    )
)
```

in the model `Employment.php` :

```
public $belongsTo=array('User'=>array(
                            'className'=>'User',
                            'foreignKey'=>'user_id'
                        )
)
```

in the model ProfessionalQualification.php :

```
public $belongsTo=array('User'=>array(
                        'className'=>'User',
                        'foreignKey'=>'user_id'
                    )
)
```

Now, in the Search form (View/Users/search.ctp) :

```
echo $this->Form->create('User');
echo $this->Form->input('name',array('type'=>'text'));
echo $this->Form->input('username',array('type'=>'text'));
echo $this->Form->input('address',array('type'=>'textarea'));
echo $this->Form->input('phone',array('type'=>'tel'));
echo $this->Form->input('degree',array('type'=>'text'));
echo $this->Form->input('passing_year',array('type'=>'text'));
echo $this->Form->input('title',array('type'=>'text'));
echo $this->Form->input('title.description',array('type'=>'textarea'));
echo $this->Form->input('company',array('type'=>'text'));
echo $this->Form->input('company.description',array('type'=>'textarea'));
echo $this->Form->input('certificate',array('type'=>'text'));
echo $this->Form->input('certificate.description',array('type'=>'textarea'));
echo $this->Form->submit('Search');
echo $this->Form->end();
```

in the `UsersController.php` controller :

```
public function search(){
    $this->set('title_for_layout','Search User');

    if($this->request->is('post')){
       $conditions=array();
       $data=$this->request->data;
   if(!empty($data['name']))
      $conditions['name']="%".$data['name']."%";
   if(!empty($data['username']))
      $conditions['username']=$data['username'];
   if(!empty($data['address']))
      $conditions['address']='%'.$data['address'].'%';
   if(!empty($data['phone']))
      $conditions['phone']=$data['phone'];
   if(!empty($data['degree']))
      $conditions['degree']="%".$data['degree']."%";
       .
       .
       .
   if(!empty($data)){
      $users=$this->User->find('all',array('conditions'=>$conditions));
          if(!empty($users)){
             $this->Session->setFlash("Searching Users Successful");
             $this->set('users',$users);
          }else
             $this->Session->setFlash("No user found");
   }else
      $this->Session->setFlash("You didn't give any info to search for");
    }
}
```

I thought it'd retrieve all data I am looking for, from all the associated tables, in an array. But, it gives an error :

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'degree' in 'where clause'

SQL Query: SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`name`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`phone`, `User`.`address`, `User`.`created`, `User`.`modified` FROM `db_name`.`users` AS `User` WHERE `degree` = 'M.Sc.'
```

Here, "degree" is from the table "Education".

Then, I used `ContainableBehavior`. In the `User.php` model :

```
public $actsAs=array('Containable');
```

In the `UsersController.php` :

```
$this->User->find('all',array('contain'=>array('Education'=>array(
                                                'conditions'=>array('Education.institution ='=>"Institute 1")
                                               ),
                                               'Employment'=>array(
                                                'conditions'=>array('Employment.employer ='=>"Employer 1")
                                               ),
                                               'ProfessionalQualification'=>array(
                                'conditions'=>array('ProfessionalQualification.certificate ='=>"Certificate 1")
                                               ),
                                               'Experience'=>array(
                                'conditions'=>array('Experience.title ='=>"Title 1")
                                               )
                         )
                 )
);
```

When I use this, the result array is :

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'User' => array(
        'name' => 'Name 3',
        'email' => 'user3@email.com',
        'mobile' => '9325028505',
        'id' => '4'
    ),
    'Education' => array(),
    'Employment' => array(),
    'ProfessionalQualification' => array(),
    'Experience' => array()
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'User' => array(
        'name' => 'Name 2',
        'email' => 'user2@email.com',
        'mobile' => '9082730572',
        'id' => '3'
    ),
    'Education' => array(),
    'Employment' => array(),
    'ProfessionalQualification' => array(),
    'Experience' => array()
),
(int) 2 => array(
    'User' => array(
        'name' => 'Name 1',
        'email' => 'user1@email.com',
        'mobile' => '715414918934',
        'id' => '2'
    ),
    'Education' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'applicant_id' => '2',
            'level' => 'Secondary',
            'degree_title' => 'S.S.C',
            'passing_year' => '2009',
            'institution' => 'Institute 1',
            'result' => '4',
            'major' => 'Science',
            'created' => '2014-05-18 16:48:08',
            'modified' => '2014-05-18 17:20:12'
        )
    ),
    'Employment' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'applicant_id' => '2',
            'employer' => 'Employer 1',
            'position_held' => 'Position 1',
            'industry' => 'Industry 1',
            'department' => 'Department 1',
            'major_responsibilities' => 'Responsibilities 1',
            'job_location' => 'Local',
            'key_achievement' => 'Achievements 1',
            'served_from' => '2005-03-12',
            'served_till' => '2007-11-26',
            'created' => '2014-05-18 16:48:08',
            'modified' => '2014-05-18 17:20:12'
        )
    ),
    'ProfessionalQualification' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'applicant_id' => '2',
            'name_of_certificate' => 'Certificate 1',
            'institute' => 'Institute 1',
            'from' => '2011-10-11',
            'to' => '2012-09-11',
            'location' => 'Local Ins.',
            'created' => '2014-05-18 16:48:08',
            'modified' => '2014-05-18 17:20:12'
        )
    ),
    'Experience' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'applicant_id' => '2',
            'title' => 'Title 1',
            'institute' => 'Institute 1',
            'training_year' => '2013',
            'location' => 'Local Ins.',
            'created' => '2014-05-18 16:48:08',
            'modified' => '2014-05-18 17:20:12'
        )
    )
),
(int) 3 => array(
    'User' => array(
        'name' => 'Name 4',
        'email' => 'user4@email.com',
        'mobile' => '9082730572',
        'id' => '5'
    ),
    'Education' => array(),
    'Employment' => array(),
    'ProfessionalQualification' => array(),
    'Experience' => array()
)
)
```

Here, notice, that I only need the 2 no. array, nothing else, but it gives me all data that are not relevant.

Can you please tell me where is the problem ? What should I do ? I guess, I have to explicitly give the table names in the form, on the specific fields, like : ModelName.0.field. What do you think?

Comment: attach behavior and specify model name with fields, it should work.

Comment: this answer may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563435/and-or-conditions-cakephp-find-for-has-many-association

Comment: No, I am sorry, this also can't help me. By the way, thanks :) . @BharatMaheshwari

Comment: I've just tried using "Containable" behavior, but I don't get the data in the format exactly what I want. It returns all data, instead of specific data. I've updated my question with the result. Can have a look at it again ? Thanks @SougataBose

Comment: if you want specific data then try to mention fields for containable behaviors.

Comment: Nope, I don't think that's the matter. I tried mentioning fields too, but it doesn't give me the specific blocks. I need only no. 2 array, because it has all the data I need. @SougataBose

Comment: where is the foreign key "user_id" on the associated tables?remove the conditions in containable.define table scema properly or define the foreign key properly on association.

Comment: See the models. Every model has the foreign key "user_id", in the $belongsTo variable. Should I define the foreign key in a different way ? And, how can I define table schema properly ? Where should I define it ? And, why should I remove the conditions from the containable ? @SougataBose

Comment: i mean is there any field on the table with label user_id?? i am not seeing any.perhaps it might be the applicant_id??

Comment: Oh, yes, its actually applicant_id, my mistake :) . But, this is same thing, here user_id or applicant_id are same. I just need a solution to my problem. @SougataBose

Comment: define foreign key => applicant_id on the relations..hope will work.

Comment: Where ? In the "contain" ? I tried defining in both the models & the contain part, but it gives error when I put the foreign key in the contain part.@SougataBose

Comment: not in contain.in the model where u r defining the relation.

Comment: Yes, I did it there, but same result. Well, how about the Searcheable Behavior ? I just got it from Google, but its for 1.3.X. @SougataBose

Comment: dont know about it.check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
  public function global_search() {
        $condition = array(
            'User.role' => array('U', 'P'),
            'User.user_status' => array('active', 'lead', 'inactive')
        );
        if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {


            $or = array(
                'PersonalInformation.first_name' => $this->request->data['User']['first_name'],
                'PersonalInformation.last_name' => $this->request->data['User']['last_name'],
                'PersonalInformation.primary_phone' => $this->request->data['User']['primary_phone'],
                'PersonalInformation.dob' => $this->request->data['User']['dob'],
                'User.email' => $this->request->data['User']['email'],
            );
            //==========This Function allow remove blank element from array=========//

            $or = array_filter($or);

            //=====End============//

            $condition = array(
                'User.role' => array('U', 'P'),
                'User.user_status' => array('active', 'lead', 'inactive'),
                'OR' => $or
            );

            $data = $this->User->find('first', array(
                'conditions' => $condition)
            );
            // pr($data); exit;
            $this->set('allusers', $data);
        }

        $data = $this->User->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => $condition)
        );
        //pr($data); exit;
        $this->set('allusers', $data);
        $this->layout = 'admin';
    }
```